# Trying to create a table with an uid field that auto-increments and is the primary key, but keep getting an error

Tags: theming, database

I'm working on an .install file for my module in Drupal 7.  I want to create two tables, one called tls_connect_floormap_images and one called tls_connect_floormap_coords.  I'm not having any trouble with the _images table.  But when I try to make the uid field of the _coords table a unique key that auto-increments, I get an error that says:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\TLSConnect3App\includes\database\mysql\schema.inc
>   on line 85

I get this error on install, When I Save Configuration I get the WSOD with the error message.  When I put in the url for /admin/modules there is an error that says Notice: Undefined variable: schema in floormap_install() (line 37 of C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\TLSConnect3App\sites\all\modules\custom\TLSConnectPackage\floormap\floormap.install).  I see that the module is installed though, and when I check for my tables in phpMyAdmin they are there, uid auto_increments but is not a unique or primary key.

Here is my code:

```
function floormap_schema(){
    $schema['floormap_images'] = array (
            'description'   => 'Floor map images.',
            'fields'        => array (
                'image'     => array('type'     => 'blob',      'not null'  => TRUE,),
                'name'      => array( 'type'        => 'varchar',       'length'        => 30,      'not null'  => TRUE,),
                'active'    => array('type'     => 'int',           'unsigned'  => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
            ),
            'unique keys'   => array('name' => array('name'),
            ),
        );  
    $schema['floormap_coords'] = array (
        'description'   => 'Floor map images.',
        'fields'        => array (
            'uid'       => array( 'type'    => 'serial',    'unsigned'  => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'floormap'  => array( 'type'    => 'text',  'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'item_type' => array( 'type'    => 'text',  'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'pos_a_x'   => array( 'type'    => 'int',       'unsigned'  => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'pos_a_y'   => array( 'type'    => 'int',       'unsiged'   => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'pos_b_x'   => array( 'type'    => 'int',       'unsigned'  => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'pos_b_y'   => array( 'type'    => 'int',       'unsiged'   => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'pos_c_x'   => array( 'type'    => 'int',       'unsigned'  => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'pos_c_y'   => array( 'type'    => 'int',       'unsiged'   => TRUE,'   not null'   => TRUE,),
            'pos_d_x'   => array('type' => 'int',       'unsigned'  => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
            'pos_d_y'   => array('type' => 'int',       'unsiged'   => TRUE,    'not null'  => TRUE,),
        ),
        'unique keys'   => array('uid' => array('uid'),),
    );  
    return $schema;
}
function floormap_install() {

    //Create table to store floor map images if it doesn't already exist
    if(!db_table_exists('tls_connect_floormap_images')){
        db_create_table('tls_connect_floormap_images',$schema['floormap_images']);
    }
    //Create table to store floor map coordinates if it doesn't already exist
    if(!db_table_exists('tls_connect_floormap_coords')){
        db_create_table('tls_connect_floormap_coords',$schema['floormap_coords']);
    }
}
```

I only get the error when I have

```
'unique keys' => array('uid' => array('uid'),),
```

in the $schema['floormap_coords'] array.  It works in the ['floormap_images'] array though, not sure why its not working for coords.  The only difference is that the 'uid' field is serial datatype and name is varchar.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please provide which version of drupal you are using ?

If you are using d7 than you don't need to check in hook_install is table exists ?

Just provide hook_schema in your module file and it will create your tables.
For floormap_coords make uid as primary ( primary key itself unique)
'primary key' => array('uid'),

Comment: I am using Drupal 7 I have already tried making it primary key and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When do you get that error message? Is it on installing the module or any time the module is loaded (i.e. a parse error).

The "Unsupported operand types" error indeed seems like something is wrong. However, it usually indicates you are doing division on an array or using a = where it should be a => or something. I tried just compiling/printing the code you pasted here in [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/UVPR3) and it appears to work fine so I don't see how you could get that error from it.

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete information.  I get this error on install, When I Save Configuration I get the WSOD with the error message.  When I put in the url for /admin/modules there is an error that says Notice: Undefined variable: schema in floormap_install() (line 37 of C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\TLSConnect3App\sites\all\modules\custom\TLSConnectPackage\floormap\floormap.install).  I see that the module is installed though, and when I check for my tables in phpMyAdmin they are there, uid auto_increments but is not a unique or primary key.